# my Google Cloud tts & Speech to text latency almost 2 minutes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I use Google Cloud Speech & TTS Python SDK

**This line for text to speech**

```
response = client.synthesize_speech(
    input=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config
    )
```

**and this line for speech to text**

```
response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)
```

but both took 2 around minutes to complete!

Then I checked my GCP API Dashboard for each service, found out that 99th percentile latency were these.

google.cloud.speech.v1.Speech.Recognize  = 3.964 seconds
google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeech.SynthesizeSpeech = 0.518 seconds

meanwhile it took 2 minutes to complete my request. My internet connection was fine (I called azure API blazingly fast)

My texts are shorts, 2 words maximum. both audio file or text input.

How can I optimize? I look it up nobody got the same issue like me.

Comment: I tried calling the API via curl, it's smooth (1s~)

Comment: Hi @Aryaputra Sudarman, you can follow the [Best practices](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices-provide-speech-data) to provide data to the Speech-to-Text API. You can also check [Frame size](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices-provide-speech-data#frame_size) as large frames can increase the latency.

Comment: I just started experimenting with the Google Cloud text to speech api and I'm seeing ~10 second latency for requests ranging in size from just a few words to several hundred characters. Since I'm just using this project for development and I'm the only one making requests, I wonder if the endpoint takes some "warming up", as in maybe GC doesn't allocate much resources to a project that doesn't get much use. @AryaputraSudarman have you seen latency drop after continued use?